# AD user authentication against a security group in ASP combining it with PHP

Tags: php, iis, asp-classic

so I am moving a small app from Winforms to a web app, and I am doing this mainly in PHP (since it is the only web scripting language I know).
So in Winforms (C#) I use this code to grant access to users (everything is done through a W2K8 server)

```
 WindowsPrincipal principal = new WindowsPrincipal(identity);
 principal.IsInRole("CKT.DEL.W_IT_RW")
```

Deepending on false or true, the app grants access to specif forms inside the app.
It is very simple from my point of view.

Now, I have PHP and IIS 7.5 inside said server, with Windows Authentication enabled.
I am able to get the logged username automatically from IE inside PHP (which is already super useful) using

```
 $_SERVER['LOGON_USER']
```

I've seen lots of questions about LDAP integration with PHP and so, but it seems way too big for me since I don't want any other thing from AD but the group auth.
So I was thinking, could it be possible to make a single page of ASP.net (or meybe classic) to authenticate the user, then send soe value in a POST variable, read it with PHP and the create a SESSION variable to keep the user authenticated?

Comment: sounds like a bad idea anyone could send a post to your php script an then is authenticated

Comment: But, how would they know what value the POST should have?